# How to make an Android app that launches one certain website?

Tags: android

I have built a mobile website for some company purposes. At the moment it is launched from the browser (Chrome on Android). But I want to cut off all the browser features that do not refer to my app (e.g. address bar, tabs switching) so that the users work only with this website.

Comment: Have a look into WebView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a WebView to load a URL:

```
   WebView webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
   webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());          
   webview .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
   webview .getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);      
   webview.loadUrl("URL");
```

And the XML code:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). Or If you want to show custom gui for the data You can get the data using HttpRequest and show them in Custom design